# How to correctly pass variables from C# console app to a PowerShell script?

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-3.5

I'm working with a .Net 3.5 console app and trying to pass a couple variables from the app to a PowerShell script.  For some reason, my script is not executing. Should the command I'm trying to pass the variables to be wrapped in a function?

C#:

```
public string oneId;
public int twoId;
public void Execute()
{
    string shellPath = "powershell.exe";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendFormat("\"& '{0}'\" ", @"C:\Active_Scripts\PSupdate.ps1");
    sb.AppendFormat(" -{0} {1} -{2} {3}", "oID", oneId, "tID", twoId);

    string result = ExecuteCommand(shellPath, sb.ToString());
}

private static string ExecuteCommand(string shellPath, string arguments)
{
    arguments = "-noprofile " + arguments;
    var process = new Process();
    var info = process.StartInfo;

    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = shellPath;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    process.Start();

    var output = process.StandardOutput;
    var error = process.StandardError;

    string result = output.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();
    return result;
}
```

PowerShell:

```
Function updateStuff
{
 param (
 [string]$entityID
 )
}

try
{
 param (
    [string]$oID, 
    [string]$tID
)
#### do some stuff
}
catch
{
}
```

Comment: Don't spawn a new `powershell.exe` process. Use the `System.Management.Automation` API to embed powershell into your console app

Comment: Have you tested the PowerShell script in isolation from the command line? Not sure if the 'param' statement will work if it's inside a 'try' block. Just a thought.

Comment: Getting an error that states System.Management.Automation needs .Net 4.0 or higher.